# java compareTo method implementation

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

currently I'm trying to find out how java's interface  "Comparable" works.
As far as I know inteface cannot have any non-static (besides default ones) methods so when we implement an interface we need to define its methods first.

But when I implement "Comparable" interface I obviously can use its compareTo method. Where is that method defined?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {

    int count = 0;

    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;

}
```

**How come that I'm able to use interface's method without even defining it?**

My apoligies if there was already an answer to that question, wasn't able to find it though.

Thx.

Comment: It's defined in the class of the objects in `anArray`.

Answer (score 4):

The elements of your `T[]` array must be of some type that implements `Comparable<T>` (as a result of the `<T extends Comparable<T>>` type bound). Therefore you can call `compareTo()` on elements of that array.

Where `compareTo` is implemented depends on which array you are passing to your method. If, for example, you pass a `String[]`, the `compareTo` method of the `String` class will be used.

Answer (score 0):

To your code:

You have defined a type T as a sub-class of "Comparable" within your signature and it is used within the parameters as you pass in an array of "T" ( T[] ). The compiler now knows that any T must be at least a Comparable.

Further information:

In general I do not suggest to implement Comparable directly. The reason for that is that comparison is always within a context you do not know.

You should favor the Comparator-interface over the Comparable-interface to implement comparisons with a specific contexts. If you want to define a natural order you can provide a natural comparator as a public constant.

Some examples:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ComparatorExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new SomeObject(1, "dhjf", "A"));
        list.add(new SomeObject(4, "ghdg", "A"));
        list.add(new SomeObject(6, "uztzt", "B"));
        list.add(new SomeObject(1, "jhgf", "C"));
        list.add(new SomeObject(3, "vbbn", "A"));
        list.add(new SomeObject(99, "cvcxc", "A"));
        list.add(new SomeObject(2, "dfdd", "G"));

        // examples

        Collections.sort(list, SomeObject.NATURAL);
        Collections.sort(list, LexicographicOrderByCategoryAndName.INSTANCE); 
        LexicographicOrderByName.INSTANCE.compare(new SomeObject(99, "cvcxc", "A"), new SomeObject(54, "fdjnn", "C"));

    }


    public static class SomeObject {

        public static Comparator<SomeObject> NATURAL = new Comparator<SomeObject>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(SomeObject arg0, SomeObject arg1) {
                return arg1.getId() - arg0.getId();
            }

        };

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String category;


        public SomeObject(int id, String name, String category) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.category = category;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

    }

    public static class LexicographicOrderByName implements Comparator<SomeObject> {

        public static LexicographicOrderByName INSTANCE = new LexicographicOrderByName();

        private LexicographicOrderByName() {
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(SomeObject o1, SomeObject o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }

    }


    public static class LexicographicOrderByCategoryAndName implements Comparator<SomeObject> {

        public static LexicographicOrderByCategoryAndName INSTANCE = new LexicographicOrderByCategoryAndName();

        private LexicographicOrderByCategoryAndName() {
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(SomeObject o1, SomeObject o2) {

            int c = o1.getCategory().compareTo(o2.getCategory());

            if (c == 0) {
                c = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }

            return c;
        }

    }


}
```

The problem with the Comparable-interface is that once you decided a specific comparison of an object you are bound to it forever. You may may change it but expect side effects as you do not know if all contexts have the same erasure and should change too.